# Implementing a tree sum using MPI

Tags: c, mpi

i'm trying to implement a tree sum using MPI.
I created a new rank number for each process. At each iteration, each process with a odd new_rank sends their value to processes with lower new_rank and returns.

This is the code:

```
void tree_sum(int rank,int size,int *value){
 int new_rank = rank;
 int remaining_processes = size/2 ;
 MPI_Status status;
 int local_value;

 while(remaining_processes > 0){

    if(is_odd_number(new_rank)){
        // Todos os processos de new_rank impar enviam
        MPI_Send(&value,1,MPI_INT,new_rank-1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        return;
    }else{
        // Todos os processos de new_rank par recebem
        MPI_Recv(&local_value,1,MPI_INT,new_rank+1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        *value += local_value;

        new_rank = new_rank / 2;

        remaining_processes--;
    }
 }  
 return;
}
```

It is failing at the last iteration. The process with new_rank=1 sends it's value to new_rank=0 but it is not been received. Process 0 gets stuck at MPI_Recv.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: is_odd_number(0) evaluates to true or false?

Comment: @CristianoSousa yes. It returns 1 if new_rank is odd and 0 otherwise. 

is_odd_number(0) returns 0. is_odd_number(13) returns 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not doing what you expect.

For the process with rank 1, he sends a message to process 0 and exists the function through return.

For the process with rank 0, first it receives a message from process 1, then it does an useless update on `new_rank` (`new_rank / 2 = 0 / 2 = 0), and in the following iteration, it is going to block on the receive because it expects a message from process with rank 1, but that process already stopped sending.

Comment: It expects to run with a even number of threads. So process 0 will receive data from a process with new_rank=1, process 1 will exit, process 2 will assume new_rank=1 (rank / 2 = 1) and process 3 will exit.

Comment: MPI doesn't work that way. You cannot change (that I know of) the external view of the rank number. Meaning, you are assigning new_rank to a differente value, but for all other processes the rank number stays the same.

Comment: You are completely right. I forgot that i had to send messages using the original rank number! Stupid mistake. Thank you =)